# How to use Geotools in Java Applets

Tags: java, applet, web, geotools

I am trying run geotools on the web and have been googling around how to run geotools in Java applets. But there is nothing I can find.

Does anyone know what is the best way to get geotools run on the web server (I'm using Apache), or is there any example Java applets that run Geotools.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoTools will work fine in an Applet or other restricted environment. The epsg-wkt plugin is explicitly set up for this environment (as it does not require access to the local file system).

Indeed applets are one of the motivations for geotools modular design (so you only include the jars you need).